# No Concept Of Regeneration Token In ServiceNow OAUTH Token Generation

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

While Creation of an OAUTH token i came across different methods to create Access Token and Refresh Token, while Access Token has life of 30 mins and Refresh Token has lifespan of 100 days, there is no way to regenerate refresh token without providing credentials again i.e Username and Password.

Is there any way to regenerate refresh token without using credentials?

below are the attached resources the i read:

**OAuth 2.0 with Service Now**

Below are the steps we can generate access_token and refresh_token

https://developer.servicenow.com/blog.do?p=/post/inbound-oauth-auth-code-grant-flow-part-1/

create an endpoint for client access

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-platform-administration/page/administer/security/task/t_CreateEndpointforExternalClients.html

Request parameters to get access_token and refresh_token

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-platform-administration/page/administer/security/reference/r_OAuthAPIRequestParameters.html

these are the response we are getting

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-platform-administration/page/administer/security/reference/r_OAuthAPIResponseParameters.html

There is not concept of regenerate token we can only do it buy increasing the token expiration time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do not need username and password, just client ID and client secret is req'd to get the new access token
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgV8Z.png)